# LWC returns empty array from apex method

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, wire

I'm trying to receive some data on the frontend using this Apex class (see below). The returned data however is an empty error. I followed the official SF documentation, made everything public and decorated with @auraEnabled, but still no data. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

```
public with sharing class AFF_Score_class {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

public static list<Overview__c> bindScore(string accountId, string programQ){
    string Account = accountId;
    string Program = programQ;

    return [
        SELECT Id, Period__c, Name, Status__c, TotalEarned__c, EarnedThisYear__c
        FROM overview__c
        WHERE programme__c = :Program
        AND account__c = :Account
    ];
}
```

This is the code in my js file:

```
@wire(bindScore) score({data, error}){
debugger;
if(data){
    console.log ("yes data")
    console.log (data)
} 
else {
    console.log ("no data")
}
```

XML:

```
    <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
    <property name="accountId" type="String" />
    <property name="programQ" type="String" />
</targetConfig>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to pass data values from an LWC to an `@AuraEnabled` method is with a second parameter to the wire call supplying values using the same names that are used in the Apex e.g.:

```
recordId;

@wire(bindScore, {accountId: recordId, programQ: 'Program Xyz'})
```

A common pattern is also to reference the property of the component `recordId` using this special syntax:

```
recordId;

@wire(bindScore, {accountId: '$recordId', programQ: 'Program Xyz'})
```

as that ensures that the wire call is made automatically anytime that value changes.

See the various examples here [Understand the Wire Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about).

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me. I added 

to the wire function{recordId: "$accountId", programPeriod: '$programPeriod'}